# How to convert Amazon Ion file to JSON format using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-ion

I want to convert Amazon Ion file from S3 bucket to JSON format.

I am trying following code

```
import json
import boto3


s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('some/path/')
ion_body = bucket.Object('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ion').get()['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
json.loads(ion_body)
```

But I am getting following `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)` error. Because in Ion file keys are declared without quotes.

Amazon Ion [document](https://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/cookbook.html#down-converting-to-json) says we can down convert Ion to Json. But I didn't get any way.
Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding: The referenced docs state a sample in java. The principle is not - as you tried- to interpret the ion encoded data as json, but instead to load via e.g. the amazon ion python module the ion data into a python object and then dump the data as json. The docs focus more on the possible precision losses, when storing the data in json as compared to ion. So, ion -> python -> json.

Answer (score 2):

The Ion Cookbook has an example for this ([reference](https://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/cookbook.html#down-converting-to-json))

In addition to amazon.ion, you'll also need to install jsonconversion.

For your case, you'd do:

```
import boto3
from amazon.ion.json_encoder import IonToJSONEncoder
from amazon.ion.simpleion import loads
import json


s3 = boto3.client('s3')
ion_body = s3.get_object(Bucket='somebucket', Key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ion')['Body'].read()
json.dumps(ion_body, cls=IonToJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: great answer - just not sure what you are importing `loads` for, it does not appear to be used

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyion2json

```
import json
import boto3
from pyion2json import ion_to_json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('some/path/')
ion_body = bucket.Object('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ion').get()['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
print(ion_to_json(ion_body))
```